# PHP: most efficient way to update an array that has as its keys correspondent to variables' names

Tags: php, arrays

Could please anyone provide some help in finding a way to process user input (from a post), which is held as variables (obviously) and in which *variables' names* are correspondent with extracted from database array's *keys*.

I'm asking this question in hope of getting not just a solution but the best (most concise) possible example.

At the moment, I could achieve it by using `loops` with `if/else` and `implode/explode`, but I thought that there is, maybe, a chance of doing it in some better way, for example, using built-in *PHP* functions made for processing arrays with usage of anonymous functions at the same time?

Code and comments:

```
// User id to be processed (extracted from a post)
$id = '8ccaa11';

// Posted new (updated) settings about the user above (extracted from a post)
$individuals_read_access = false;
$individuals_write_access = false;
$calendar_read_access = false;
$calendar_write_access = true;
$documents_read_access = true
$documents_write_access = false


// Current records extracted from database
Array
(
    [individuals_read_access] => 8ccaa11
    [individuals_write_access] => 8ccaa11
    [calendar_read_access] => 8ccaa11|00cc00aa
    [calendar_write_access] => 8ccaa11
    [documents_read_access] => 8ccaa11
    [documents_write_access] => 8ccaa11
)

// Expected array to be posted back to database
Array
(
    [individuals_read_access] => 
    [individuals_write_access] => 
    [calendar_read_access] => 00cc00aa
    [calendar_write_access] => 8ccaa11
    [documents_read_access] => 8ccaa11
    [documents_write_access] => 
)
```

Could anyone please help to find the best and most concise solution to get *expected array*?

Comment: What if the user's input is also stored in an array with the expected format?

Comment: @zerkms Alright, possible indeed. What is then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem about an solution using anonymous function is that you cannot access your variables. I created two solutions to demonstrate the case:

Version 1 was removed by request of Illis, see post history :)

Version 2. Inputs as array, use can pass them easily to the anonymous function. Read more about [closures](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php) and [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

```
<?php

$id = '8ccaa11';


$inputs = [
    'individuals_read_access' => false,
    'individuals_write_access' => false,
    'calendar_read_access' => false,
    'calendar_write_access' => true,
    'documents_read_access' => true,
    'documents_write_access' => false
];


// Current records extracted from database
$records = [
    'individuals_read_access' => '8ccaa11',
    'individuals_write_access' => '8ccaa11',
    'calendar_read_access' => '8ccaa11|00cc00aa',
    'calendar_write_access' => '8ccaa11',
    'documents_read_access' => '8ccaa11',
    'documents_write_access' => '8ccaa11'
];

array_walk($records, function(&$value, $key) use ($inputs, $id) {
    if (!isset($inputs[$key])) {
        continue;
    }

    $rights = empty($value) ? [] : explode('|', $value);
    $index = array_search($id, $rights);

    if (!$inputs[$key] && $index !== false) {
        unset($rights[$index]);
    } else {
        array_push($rights, $id);
    }

    $value = implode('|', array_unique($rights));
});


var_dump($records);
```

Comment: Thank you Otanaught, but I'm only interested in a second example, really, as I mentioned before. Your second example, thought, it's nice and pretty close to what I expected, looses already pre-stored value, which is `00cc00aa` ( you have to throw away or add a value, not just re-write). It's an update and previous values has to be stored. This is where  I see using `explode/implode`. +1 Thanks for your effort.

Comment: What rules does the explode, implode follow? Does it remove always the first element when the input is true?

Comment: @Otanaught: Look it up in the documentation and find out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry but what? I am askin Ilia what rules i have to follow to get the desired element out of his string so i can apply the changes to my code.

Comment: Simple. Pretend you have `'calendar_read_access' => '8ccaa11|00cc00aa|aacc00|acac11'` so in case `$id = '8ccaa11'` and `calendar_read_access = false` the Output is: `'calendar_read_access' => '00cc00aa|aacc00|acac11'`. Next, if lets say `$id = '000099'` and `calendar_read_access = true`, then already existing `'calendar_read_access' => '8ccaa11|00cc00aa|aacc00|acac11'` should add new value of `000099` and become: `'calendar_read_access' => '8ccaa11|00cc00aa|aacc00|acac11|000099'`.

Comment: @Otanaught Great `array_walk()` example, by the way! That was my kinda of a problem. Need to work more on *passing as a reference* (`&$value`) thing. Thanks, my friend. It's already good. If you can edit your answer, I'd be appreciate. I would remove the first example though.

Comment: @Otanaught I thought that you can only use `use` to refer to an external, fully qualified name with an alias in Object-oriented programming, like `use My\Full\NSname;` Where I can read more about what you have expressed? Provide some explanations to what you're doing in `array_walk()` please. Really cool, man!! :)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev updated the example. I also linked the php documentation about closures and array_walk. can you be more specific what you want to know? Ill be glad to help.

Comment: @Otanaught Thank you!There is an error in a part that parses values, (`'8ccaa11|00cc00aa|aacc00|acac11'`). It doesn't remove it from the final array.

Comment: @Otanaught In case the `$records` array has empty value, afterwards it get `|` delimiter at the beginning, like this `|000099`. And it doesn't either add/remove nessesary `$id` after all. Could you please fix it?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Fixed, i added an empty check for $value.